# Sending data to another view: can't unwrap option

Tags: swift

I know that this has to be a simple fix, but can't seem to understand why my code is not working. Basically I am trying to send a value from a text field in 1 view to a 2nd view's label.

ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var Text1st: UITextField
@IBAction func Goto2ndView(sender: AnyObject) {


    let view2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as MyView2
    //view2.Label2nd.text=text;
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}
```

MyView2.swift

```
@IBOutlet var Label2nd: UILabel

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var VC = ViewController()

    var string = (VC.Text1st.text) //it doesn't like this, I get a 'Can't unwrap Option.. error'
    println(string)
}
```

-------EDITED UPDATED CODE FROM (drewag)-------

ViewController.swift

```
    let text = "text"
    var sendString = Text1st.text
    println(sendString) //successfully print it out.
    let view2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as MyView2
    view2.Label2nd.text=sendString;
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
```

MyView2.swift

```
@IBOutlet var Label2nd: UILabel

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var VC = ViewController()

    var string = self.Label2nd.text
    println(string) //still getting the error of an unwrap optional.none

}
```

Comment: I know Swift doesn't have any access modifiers, I tried some more test and debugging and found that whenever you try to access something from a different class, if it's not on that class it will come back as nil. If anyone can point me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure self.navigationController isn't nil?

Comment: It segues to the next view, so I highly doubt it has anything do with nagivationController. No way it's nil, that would be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var VC = ViewController()` creates a new instance of ViewController. Unless there is a default value, you are not going to get any value out of `VC.Text1st.text`. You really should use a string variable on your second view controller to pass the data to it.

Also, a note on common formatting:

1. Class names should start with a capital letter (as you have)
2. Method / function names should start with a lower case letter
3. UIViewController subclasses should have "Controller" included in their name, otherwise, it looks like it is a subclass of UIView which is an entirely different level of Model View Controller (the architecture of all UIKit and Cocoa frameworks)

**Edit**:

Here is some example code:

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController {
    ...

    func goToSecondView() {
        var viewController = ViewController2()
        viewController.myString = "Some String"
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewController2 : UIViewController {
    var myString : String?

    func methodToUseMyString() {
        if let string = self.myString {
            println(string)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note, I am not creating ViewController2 using a storyboard. I personally prefer avoiding storyboards because they don't scale well and I find editing them to be very cumbersome. You can of course change it to create the view controller out of the storyboard if you prefer.

Comment: ok so this makes a lot of sense, however if I do 'self' in my 2nd view class, wouldn't that refer to that class and not ViewController?

Comment: self refers to the class that you are currently writing the code in. That is why you need to set the data when transitioning like in the code you have commented out. Then, through self in the second view controller, you can access that data.

Comment: Ok so I changed what I had to your suggestion, and I'm still getting the unwrap error. I updated my code for you in the OP if you want to look at it. the ONLY other solution I can think of, if you are right, is that perhaps it's because I have it in the "viewDidLoad" although I don't think that would be why.

Comment: in fact I am getting the unwrap error as soon as it hits the "view2.Label2nd.text=sendString;" line

Comment: @user3685907 Are you sure that `Label2nd` is connected properly in your storyboard. Try just printing out `self.Label2nd`

Comment: Yep works fine, I set it's value to "hello" when I run app, and get to the 2nd view, my Label2nd works properly. I ended up taking the "view2.Label2nd.text=sendString" out because whatever I tried it kept giving me a unwrap error. I am kind of perplexed at this moment as to why something as simple as accessing a variable from a different is so difficult.

Comment: @user3685907 Honestly, it isn't that difficult, you just have some small error somewhere that I can't think of without seeing the entire working project.

Comment: yeah all it was was a simple class instance problem. Basically I just needed to add a class instance this way: "var VC: ViewController" and then in my ViewController I needed to set self to VC, and then it worked. Thanks for the help man I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3685907 that is not really any different than my solution and there is no reason for ViewController2 to know about ViewController1 just to pass a simple string. This is bad code architecture but I understand your desire to move on from this problem for now.

Comment: well how would you do it differently that would be good code architecture? I'm assuming you mean without calling the instance in the 2ndViewController

Comment: Just drawing out what you said in my head, wouldn't you need a class instance somewhere though? If I didn't do it in  my 2nd view controller, I would have to do it in my first, no?

Comment: Your class instances are being created when you load them from your storyboard. Really, a good architecture would be simply this: 1. ViewController2 defines a property `var myString : String?` 2. When presenting `ViewController2`, `ViewController1` sets that `myString` property 3. ViewController2 can test and use `self.myString` whenever it wants. If you had more reputation I could explain better in chat...

Comment: i'll look more into that because you're right, creating an entire instance of a class when not needed should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

jatoben is correct that you want to use optional binding. IBOutlets are automatically optionals so you should check the textfield to see if it is nil.

```
if let textField = VC.Text1st {
    println(textField.text)
}
```

This should prevent your app from crashing, but it will not print out anything because your text field has not yet been initialized.

Edit:

If you want to have a reference to your initial ViewController inside your second you're going to have to change a few things. First add a property on your second viewcontroller that will be for the first view controller:

```
@IBOutlet var Label2nd: UILabel //existing code
var firstVC: ViewController? //new
```

Then after you create view2, set it's firstVC as the ViewController you are currently in:

```
let view2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as MyView2 //already in your code
view2.firstVC = self //new
```

Finally in your viewDidLoad in your second view controller, use firstVC instead of the ViewController you recreated. It will look something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let textField = firstVC?.Text2nd {
        println(textField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes I am actually aware of this, except this is not the answer because the whole reason it is nil is because I am having trouble sending the data to the second class. So basically the text field is not nil, I am entering data into it, and I test this by trying a println in my first class, in which it works. Which only tells me that the data just isn't being sent to the second class, which would cause that unwrap error, in which you and jatoben are 100% correct, but that's a problem BECAUSE of my initial problem.

Comment: @user3685907 So you're trying to get information from the text field of the original view controller? If that is the case, you shouldn't be making a new ViewController because it won't have the same information

Comment: That would make no sense at all for what I am trying to do though, why would I want the same view?

Comment: @user3685907 aren't you trying to use text from the first view in the second view?

Comment: yes, that would be what I am trying to do "Basically I am trying to send a value from a text field in 1 view to a 2nd view's label."

Comment: @user3685907 when you call ViewController(), you are making a new ViewController. VC does not point to your original ViewController

Comment: so instead would I do something like: "var vc: ViewController?"

Comment: You are point on sir, thank you. May I ask how you knew this? I tried looking ALL over the internet to find some documentation on this. I also looked at previous objective-c projects I did and this is not the same way. Upvoted and checked your answer, and props for knowing this.

Comment: just practice. Just remember that calling a constructor like ViewController() creates a new object and won't have any of your old data

Comment: yeah i guess i just assumed even if it made a new object, based on sequential programming, it would still have the necessary value attached. Guess not though. In most languages you create instances by "importing" header files or, something of that sort, so i think that kind of threw me off not being able to simply just import a header like you could in c++ or objective-c (if my memory serves me correctly, obj-c allowed you to do that).

Comment: @user3685907 neither c++ nor objective-C allow you to create instances simply by importing a header. You seem to have some confusion about how non-scripting languages work.

Comment: Well I'm not an expert, but I am 100% sure you can do that in C++. I've done it many times, although you said "simply by importing a header", you must have assumed I meant that just allows you to create the instance, not the instance itself. If that's the case, then yes, you would have to actually type out "Instance instance = new Instance()" (C++). I actually am more confused on how scripting languages work, rather than non-scripting. I only know programming languages.

Comment: Actually in C++ all you would need to do is "ClassName instanceName". So no, I am not confused at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Use optional binding to unwrap the property:

```
if let string = VC.Text1st.text {
  println(string)
}
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but I tried it for the hell of it and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get a compiler error or crash, or did it just not print the string?

Comment: Ok well I think your answer is actually part of my problem, another part, and the main part actually, is that I am unable to pass the variable to the class (for some reason) and so it IS coming nil, causing the unwrap error (my best guess). Instead of your solution, which might be true, the real problem is being able to access the value inside of the text field in my first view. I can access that value in my first class, no problem, except when I try to access it in my second view. I get to my second view from the button in my first class.